# Как результат ввода из цикла записать в объект?

Tags: javascript, obj, prompt

Подскажите пожалуйста, как надо дописать цикл, чтобы результат ввода записывался в объект  appData.expenses?

В объекте это отображалось так.

```
expenses: {
    “Наименование товара1” : “Цена товара1”,
    “Наименование товара2” : “Цена товара2”
}
```

Часть кода ниже. Надо На основании его дописать цикл таким образом, чтобы выполнялись условия описаны выше.

Спасибо.

```
let appData = {
    expenses: {},
    value: 0,
    askExpenses: {},
    asking: function() {
        for (let i=0; i < 2; i++) {
            appData.askExpenses[i] = prompt('Наименование товара');
            appData.value[i] = +prompt('Цена товара');
            }
    }
};
appData.asking();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
asking: function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    let mName = prompt('Наименование товара');
    let mPrice = +prompt('Цена товара');
    this.expenses[mName] = mPrice; 
  }
}
```